# Python : making an intrusion detection system

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a network ids.

```
from scapy.all import *
from datetime import datetime

class ids:
    __flagsTCP = {
        'F': 'FIN',
        'S': 'SYN',
        'R': 'RST',
        'P': 'PSH',
        'A': 'ACK',
        'U': 'URG',
        'E': 'ECE',
        'C': 'CWR',
        }

    __ip_cnt_TCP = {}               #ip address requests counter

    __THRESH=1000               

    def sniffPackets(self,packet):
        if packet.haslayer(IP):
            pckt_src=packet[IP].src
            pckt_dst=packet[IP].dst
            print("IP Packet: %s  ==>  %s  , %s"%(pckt_src,pckt_dst,str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))), end=' ')

        if packet.haslayer(TCP):
            src_port=packet.sport
            dst_port=packet.dport
            print(", Port: %s --> %s, "%(src_port,dst_port), end='')
            print([type(self).__flagsTCP[x] for x in packet.sprintf('%TCP.flags%')])
            self.detect_TCPflood(packet)
        else:
            print()


    def detect_TCPflood(self,packet):
        if packet.haslayer(TCP):
            pckt_src=packet[IP].src
            pckt_dst=packet[IP].dst
            stream = pckt_src + ':' + pckt_dst

            if stream in type(self).__ip_cnt_TCP:
                type(self).__ip_cnt_TCP[stream] += 1
            else:
                type(self).__ip_cnt_TCP[stream] = 1

            for stream in type(self).__ip_cnt_TCP:
                pckts_sent = type(self).__ip_cnt_TCP[stream]
                if pckts_sent > type(self).__THRESH:
                    src = stream.split(':')[0]
                    dst = stream.split(':')[1]
                    print("Possible Flooding Attack from %s --> %s"%(src,dst))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("custom packet sniffer ")
    sniff(filter="ip",iface="enp0s3",prn=ids().sniffPackets)
```

Output:

```
IP Packet: 192.168.1.10  ==>  192.168.1.5  , 2017-10-18 13:50:49 , Port: 10920 --> 0, ['SYN']
Possible Flooding Attack from 192.168.1.10 --> 192.168.1.5
Possible Flooding Attack from 192.168.1.5 --> 192.168.1.10
IP Packet: 192.168.1.10  ==>  192.168.1.5  , 2017-10-18 13:50:49 , Port: 11079 --> 0, ['SYN']
Possible Flooding Attack from 192.168.1.10 --> 192.168.1.5
Possible Flooding Attack from 192.168.1.5 --> 192.168.1.10
IP Packet: 192.168.1.5  ==>  192.168.1.10  , 2017-10-18 13:50:49 , Port: 0 --> 11744, ['RST', 'ACK']
```

Using:

```
hping3 -S --flood -V 192.168.1.5
```

The problem is the output, that is very ambiguous as which one is attacking to whom.
This is because the no. of request is getting past that threshold(1000) after some seconds after executing the program.
If I focus based on flags like 'SYN' but the hping3 tool is able to flood with any flags. Please help, any ideas would be greatfull..

Comment: what output are you expecting?

Comment: I just want this ouput : Possible Flooding Attack from 192.168.1.10 --> 192.168.1.5

Comment: Probably this project may help you https://bitbucket.org/camp0/aiengine/